# PHP - Issue with FONT echo

Tags: php

I've started coding php 4 days ago and I'm wondering why I get the output:

```
Array['username']
```

When running this code:

```
$users = array(
    array('username' => 'AlphaColors','email' => 'Cheese', 'Likes'=> array('reading','gaming')),
    array('username' => 'BetaColors','email' => 'Melon', 'Likes'=> array ('looking on youtube','learning')),
    array('username'=> 'DeltaColors','email' => 'Food', 'Likes'=> array ('flipping a switch','looking at the light'))
);

echo "<p style = 'font:20px calibri'> $users[1]['username'] </font>";
```

And not just the full array.

It must be a really dumb and obvious mistake of me but I can't find it myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your $users[1][‘username’] in curly brackets {$users[1][‘username’]}

Comment: You don't even get the p style?

Comment: You’re trying to call the $users array from inside the string, so php doesn’t know that you mean for [‘username’] to be interpreted as code. The curly braces are a special character in the string essentially saying ‘everything in here should be interpreted as code’

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The style is not applied as an attribute. (Hint: missing `=`).

Comment: Thanks Qirel! Didn't even take notice of the style not even applying.

Comment: @Qirel It's inline style, so  nothing is wrong. But `</font>` must be `</p>`

Comment: @Smartpal The inline style was missing it's value in the original post. It was since edited after my comment.

Answer (score 2):

To concatenate strings you can use either the end string and dot method or `"` and curly braces.

```
echo "<p style 'font:20px calibri'>". $users[1]['username'] ."</font>"
```

Or

```
echo "<p style 'font:20px calibri'> {$users[1]['username']} </font>";
```

Choose the one that suits you the best.
I don't think there is any difference in performance, if there is it's probably less than what a comment or two does.

Comment: The html is not valid though. Both the tags and the attributes, might be worth noting.

Comment: @Qirel true, but that is not the question really. And OP seems to have understood it already.